# EOS - How to understand license agreement of Linux kernel derivative?

Tags: linux-kernel, licenses, gpl, open-source, software-distribution

Background:

> Software licensing generally mean, you don't own software, but you own the right to use it - a license to use it.
>
> One criticism about EULA is that it is often pretty lengthy.
>   For example: Paypal license agreement is 64K words long.
>
> Software license is often pretty complex to understand with it's lawyer terminology.
>
> Example1: Facebook, at one place says, *you own all of the content* and later says, *you grant us a* ....
>
> [image]
>   Example2: Gamestation license:
>
> As an April Fool's Day joke, Gamestation added a clause stating that users who placed an order on April 1, 2010 agreed to irrevocably give their soul to the company, which 7,500 users agreed to. Although there was a checkbox to exempt out of the **"immortal soul"** clause, few users checked it and thus Gamestation concluded that 88% of their users did not read the agreement.
>
> I learnt that money can be made out of open source license.
>
> I learnt that there are 70 different licenses related to open source

---

Considering [EOS](https://www.arista.com/assets/data/pdf/EOSWhitepaper.pdf) operating system, to be specific,  which is the industry-leading, Linux-
based network operating system,

EOS runs across the entire portfolio of Arista’s network switches as well as in a virtual machine instance (vEOS)

`EOS` operating system being one customisation of Linux kernel used for commercial reasons, I would like to understand the license aspect in terms of,

```
Installation rights
Customisation rights
Distribution rights
Support
```

for using Linux derivative, as commercial product.

[Here](https://www.arista.com/en/support/product-documentation/eos-feature-licensing) is EOS distribution model

Arista [also distributes](https://www.sdxcentral.com/articles/news/arista-creates-containerized-open-version-eos/2017/03/) open source EOS that can run on hardware other than Arista switches.

Linux kernel is under GPLv2 distribution model

---

Question:

1) Which clause of GPLv2 allow such vendors( like Arista) to sell EOS?

2) Does Arista(vendor) suppose to distribute EOS with source code or as closed source?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about license laws.

Comment: @dr01 Is it appropriate  to migrate to opensource.stackexchange?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what to look for in the verbose background you give, so I'll just answer the questions.

> 1) Which clause of GPLv2 allow such vendors (like Arista) to sell [derivatives of the Linux kernel]?

The first one. It explicitly allows distribution and taking a fee. Though clause 6 gives the recipients a right to re-distribute it, possibly for free.

> 2) [Is] Arista (vendor) suppose[d] to distribute EOS with source code or as closed source?

Clause 3 sets requirements for distributing in object code or executable form, namely requiring that they be accompanied by either a) the source code, b) a written offer for the source, or c) information you received on where to find it, but that only applies for non-commercial distribution. 
Note that this includes derived works, meaning modified versions of the original.

[The license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html) isn't too complicated, I would suggest reading it in full.